# Linux command and single quote

Tags: linux, command, single-quotes

I thought the single quotes simply reserve the literal value of each character within the quotes and do not interfere with the command result except for those character-escaping situations.

For example, the two commands below returned the same result.

```
$ ls /home/testuser/tmp1
$ ls '/home/testuser/tmp1'
```

This command below ran successfully.

```
$ cp /home/testuser/tmp1/* /home/testuser/tmp2
```

However, the command below ran into error.

```
$ cp '/home/testuser/tmp1/*' /home/testuser/tmp2 
cp: cannot stat '/home/testuser/tmp1/*': No such file or directory
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: You're explicitly preventing the glob expansion, and as it tells you there isn't a file literally named `*` in that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` is what you call a character escaping situation. Since you preserved the literal value of `*`, it lost its meaning of "all files", and `cp` instead tries to copy a file named literally `*`.

When you run:

```
cp /home/testuser/tmp1/* /home/testuser/tmp2
```

The shell will transparently rewrite it into:

```
cp /home/testuser/tmp1/bar /home/testuser/tmp1/foo /home/testuser/tmp2
```

This process is known as "pathname expansion" or "globbing". When you quote the `*`, this rewrite does not happen.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The reason I use single quotes is to handle a mounted windows file system, which has spaces in folder/file name. Now I have two more questions. 1. I understand that Linux accepts space in file/folder names. But the best practice is not to use spaces in any name, am I right? 2. If a directory name does contain spaces, how do I handle this file mask situation, aka copying all files?

Comment: For my second question, I think I have to escape the space, right?
For example,
cp /home/testuser/tmp\ 1/* /home/testuser/tmp2

Comment: 1. It's best practices to avoid spaces and exotic characters in system files that are distributed broadly, but it's fine to have spaces in filenames for a user's data files and any tool that doesn't handle a filename like `Family Photos` is considered buggy. Sometimes users avoid this so they can write sloppier scripts for themselves, but that's their choice. 2. You can escape individual spaces or just quote everything *except* the `*`, like `'/home/testuser/tmp1/'*`